# Use hiddenfield-value for asp-route-parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

Ive got a hidden field in a _PartialView with the value I want (jQuery fills it up)
I need this same value in a (foreach) asp-route-parameter

```
<div class="js-products-list">
 <input id="cropIdForProdBaseJQ" type="hidden" value="" />
  @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
  {
    <a asp-controller="XXX" asp-action="YYY" asp-route-language="@Model.CurrentLanguage" asp-route-cropId="" id="productCard">
  }
```

So, asp-route-cropId should get the value from the hiddenfield, to pass it along as parameter

I tried using a jQueryfunction (without any luck) like

```
var neededValue = the value I got from another jQfunction
$('#productCard').attr("asp-route-cropId", neededValue);
```

Can it be done?
  How would i approach this?
  Thanks!

Comment: if I Console.log 
    `$('#productCard').attr("asp-route-cropId");`
before and after 
    `$('#productCard').attr("asp-route-cropId", neededValue);`
I do get the correct and updated value in my script.. but not in the asp-route-cropId itself though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by adding a data-producttypeId in the a-tag; changed productCard from 'id' to 'class'

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Products)

{
<a asp-controller="XXX" asp-action="YYY" asp-route-language="@Model.CurrentLanguage" asp-route-cropId="" class="productCard" 
data-producttypeId="@product.ProductTypeId">
}
```

I added a jQuery function:

```
$('.productCard').click(function(e) {    
var cropId = $('#croptype-filter-From-ProductType').val();

var clickedCard = $(this);
var baseUrl = clickedCard.attr("href");

var newUrl = baseUrl.replace("crop-ID", cropId);
window.location.href = newUrl;
});
```

A replace on a string creates a new string instead of actually replacing it.
After placing the newly created string in the href, all was good!
Thanks for the input guys, gave me some good leads!

Answer (score 2):

The razor attributes are consumed when the html is generated. If you're referencing this from javascript you would need an attribute that persists after the page is compiled. This is tricky in your case because you're trying to materialize a route after the request has completed.

Instead, the nice semantic way of passing input values to actions is with a form instead of trying to build an anchor dynamically.

```
<form method="get" asp-controller="XXX" asp-action="YYY" asp-route-language="@Model.CurrentLanguage">
    <input id="cropIdForProdBaseJQ" type="hidden" value="" />
    @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
    {
        @* Assuming you are doing something useful with "product" here *@
        <button name="PassThisId" value="@product.ProductId">Press me!</button>
    }
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The tag helpers in razor view gets executed on server and the result of that (HTML markup) will be send to browser and browser will render it. So at this time, the anhcor tag helper already generated the href attribute value of the link.

What you can do is, override the normal link click behavior using JavaScript, read the input element value from your page and use that to build a new URL and navigate to that.

You can give a dummy value for your cropId param.

```
<a asp-controller="invoices" asp-action="GetData" asp-route-name="@Model.supplierName" asp-route-cropId=1 id="productCard">Click me</a>
```

In JavaScript

```
 $("#productCard").click(function (e) {
            // Stop the normal navigation
            e.preventDefault();

            //Build the new URL
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            var date = $("#cropIdForProdBaseJQ").val();
            url = url.replace(1, date);

            //Navigate to the new URL
            window.location.href = url;

        });
```