# How to set asp-route variable from javascript prompt?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

In my _Layout.cshtml page, I have several menu elements, e.g.

```
  <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="CsvReports" asp-action="MyAction" asp-route-currentYear="2017" asp-route-nextYear="2018">Accounting Report</a>
```

As you can see, asp-route-currentYear and asp-route-nextYear are hard-coded. The values are passed to the controller. But is it possible to get those values from the user through e.g. javascript prompt? As these links are in my layout page, and thus can be clicked wherever the user may be at that point, I would prefer to avoid creating a view for each link.

Comment: No. It's not possible. The route attributes are process server-side before the client even gets anything. JavaScript runs client-side, long after the server is done.

Comment: @Chris Pratt Thank you very much. Don't you know any alternative way how this can be done (I mean getting data from the user by javascript prompt and passing it to the controller without a separate view)?

Comment: No, because that's not how HTTP works on a fundamental level. You have a request-response cycle. The client requests the page, and the server responds, and it's done. Any thing else the client wants must happen via a new request, resulting in yet another new response. You *can* use JS to alter the link, after the fact, but that's janky. More likely than not, this is a situation where you should have a form, not a link, and submit those values to the server.

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144468/use-hiddenfield-value-for-asp-route-parameter