# Hide parameter from url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Just curious how or is there's a method in asp that  can hide the parameter in the url without using jquery, javascripts? im using asp.net core mvc in my project and passing parameters from view to controller through tag helpers such as asp-route-Identifier etc. [image]

```js
sample a tag:
<a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Exposure" asp-action="ViewPolicies" asp-route-Identifier="@ViewBag.Identifier"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> View Information: <b> @ViewBag.TotalPolicy</b></a>
```

Comment: `<a></a>` Send  Get request by default and `asp-route-xx` will map the data to the url in the format of `?xx=your data`. Do you just need a label or button that doesn't display the data in the url to pass the data？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to show parameter in url, You can put the data in the form then send post request. Refer to this code:

```
public class PassModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
    @model PassModel
    <form asp-controller="Exposure" asp-action="ViewPolicies" method="post">
         <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Value" value="@ViewBag.Identifier"/>
        <button type="submit">View Information: <b>@ViewBag.TotalPolicy</b> </button>
    </form>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ViewPolicies(PassModel model){
   //......
}.
```

If you want to hidden url by using `<a></a>` and `asp-route-xx`, you need to use js or jq, please refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144468/use-hiddenfield-value-for-asp-route-parameter).